# overflow-y eating CSS properties

Tags: css

I created a div tag with long text, so i decided to use overflow-y:auto; but applying this eats away my css properties like upper triangle, and glow effect in MY BROWSER.

view fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/SFVC3/

```
.message_box {
    position: absolute;
    top:80px;
    right:5px;
    width: 350px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background:#fff;
    visibility: hidden;
    max-height:400px;
overflow-y:auto;
    border:solid 1px #719ECE; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 3px; 
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 10px rgba(113,158,206,0.8));
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(113,158,206,0.8);
    filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 10px rgba(113,158,206,0.8));
    z-index:9999;
}

.message_box:after, .message_box:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    border: solid transparent; 
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;

}

.message_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-width: 9px;
    right: 10%;
    margin-right: -9px;    
}
.message_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(113, 158, 206, 0); 
    border-bottom-color: #719ECE;
    border-width: 10px;
    right: 10%;
    margin-right: -10px; 


}
```

Comment: You should add an extra outer div which contains the styling and then apply `overflow-y: auto` to the immediate child element.

Comment: Yes, what @Duopixel said :-) Here’s a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SFVC3/2/ And if you want the scrollbar directly inside the border, then move the padding to the inner element as well.

Comment: That solves half of my problem, now my message_box is closing when i click anywhere in page!

Comment: that's because it closes when you click on html.

Comment: Yes i know, now its closing when i click on itself.